# How do I disable the border and background color controls in Tridion 2011's rich text table options?

Tags: 2011

In Tridion 2011 for the Rich text field table options, How can I disable the Border color and Background Color controls?

Answer (score 8):

This is done on the Schema.  It is covered in the online documentation [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_14_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8) ([login required](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

1) Select the rich text field and then click on the 'Edit Formatting Features',

[image]

2) Change the settings in the 'Allowed Actions' tab of the formatting features popup

[image]